# How to get always the new rows from a table using SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I have a table which has more than 80,000,000 records. I want to import the new records from this table "A" in other table "B".

At the beginning I imported all records in a new table "B". Now I want to get/Import from table "A" all the new added records which were added after the last import. I have a column which represent the date and time of the record IN table "A". So, is there some way to say import all lines were from source table "A" where record date-time > Last record date-time in destination table "B".

Answer (score 3):

If A and B are on the same server, you can just do a sub-query to B in your query of A that you use as your Source transformation.

If they are on different servers, use an Execute SQL task to get the last Date-time from B and populate a variable with it.   Then reference the variable in your query of A in the source transformation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second solution is exactly what i was looking for :)